# List of Linked Documents for a Revit file through Forge

Tags: autodesk-forge

Is there a Forge API which can be used to query the linked documents for a Revit file? Not sure if it would be more related to Document Management or Model Derivatives, but either way it would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I tried that API, but I am getting 404 error. Here is what I am doing:

I use [this API](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-folders-folder_id-contents-GET/) to get the content of a folder on BIM 360. It contains 4 files and they are all Revit files. Here is the response that I am getting:

```
{'data': [{...}, {...}, {...}, {...}], 'included': [{...}, {...}, {...}, {...}], 'jsonapi': {'version': '1.0'}, 'links': {'self': {...}}}
```

Then I grab the id from every item:

```
{'attributes': {'createTime': '2020-12-15T18:23:36.0000000Z', 'createUserId': 'V6BXQE6V6XF2', 'createUserName': 'Ehsan Barekati', 'displayName': 'link1.rvt', 'extension': {...}, 'hidden': False, 'lastModifiedTime': '2020-12-15T18:23:57.0000000Z', 'lastModifiedUserId': 'V6BXQE6V6XF2', 'lastModifiedUserName': 'Ehsan Barekati', ...}, 'id': 'urn:adsk.wipprod:dm...Xli18FVAA', 'links': {'self': {...}}, 'relationships': {'links': {...}, 'parent': {...}, 'refs': {...}, 'tip': {...}, 'versions': {...}}, 'type': 'items'}
```

In this case, the id is: 'urn:adsk.wipprod:dm.lineage:udIEwiUQTAiB-Xli18FVAA'

and generate the base64 encoded value. (Which is: 'dXJuOmFkc2sud2lwcHJvZDpkbS5saW5lYWdlOnVkSUV3aVVRVEFpQi1YbGkxOEZWQUE')Then I call the API that you referenced and I am getting 404. What am I missing?